# Has anyone run into these two Winter 13 preview issues?

Tags: ide, logging, bug, api-26

I know the Winter 13 preview has only just appeared, but I've run into two issues and am wondering if anyone else can reproduce them.

1. I'm having trouble deploying code from a standard dev org (Summer 12) using the latest Eclipse IDE into a Winter 13 sandbox. The deployment fails after only a few seconds with an error "Unable to deploy Force.com components." Reason "REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG: Your request was running for too long and has been stopped. (**UPDATE** - I was finally able to deploy the project by deploying different types of components individually - first custom settings, then some custom fields and custom labels - finally Apex classes and VF pages. So it looks like this problem related in some way to dependency analysis on deployment. No idea if it is new to Winter 13, or if I just got unlucky with a bad combination of deployment components).
2. I'm having trouble overriding the default log levels (I want to remove workflows and validation rules from the logs). On the developer console and debug monitoring it seems to have no effect. On the test class level I'm seeing a number of results:

   - Sometimes it has no effect
   - Sometimes I get an internal server error with a mysterious error number
   - Sometimes it works.

Please post a comment/answer if you have any suggestion or insights. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, The API versions are changed in Sandboxes to 26. We faced problem in Changeset and came to know about this.

Comment: Yes - but this is an Eclipse IDE deployment. As mentioned in the update, it's not clear this was a Winter 13 related issue.

Comment: We ran into a similar issue, using Change Sets, moving from a v26 sandbox to a v25 sandbox.
I received an *Operation Timeout* message when I attempted to deploy the CS. Not the regular "*Yeah, this is gonna take a while. I'll email you when done*" message, but an actual timeout error. It popped up right after I clicked deploy and I was able to replicate it using another CS. After this timeout, the CS seemed to end up in limbo - it said "In Progress" but never finished.

Comment: Based on past experience, I would never attempt to deploy from an (API+1) version to an (API) version and assume success; your best bet is to always plan your releases such that you're deploying to equal or higher API environments. Backwards compatibility is "guaranteed", but forwards compatibility is not possible to guarantee.

Comment: It sounds to me that there is an obscure issue out there, but not one that is clear or easy to reproduce. What you are describing sounds exactly like the changeset equivalent of what I saw.

Comment: I guess its due to some dependency and bug in SFDC itself .Please check with them